# Unable to load Axios in Node even though it is installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, axios

I have a Jasmine test with some HTTP requests in it. I'm using Axios for the promise based HTTP access but for some reason I'm getting `axios is not defined`. I have already run `npm install axios --save`

```
var request = require('axios');
var constants = require('../../lib/constants.js');

describe('Signing into the application', function () {
    it('returns 200 OK', function () {
        axios.get(constants.Endpoint)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    });
});
```

Here is the output:

```
Failures:

  1) Signing into the application returns 200 OK
   Message:
     ReferenceError: axios is not defined
   Stacktrace:
     ReferenceError: axios is not defined
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (C:\Users\la\Documents\tests\spec\integration\sign-in\sign-in-spec.js:6:9)
```

Here is the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "actual-tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine-node spec"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "jasmine-node": "^1.14.5"
  }
}
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined:

```
var request = require('axios');
```

And trying to call:

```
axios.get ...
```

Change it to:

```
var axios = require('axios');
```

Comment: Damn, that was too obvious. Thanks