# Unable to install Axios to Node -- Tried several StackOverflow solutions to no avail

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Node is unable to find the axios package I installed. In NPM I tried the following (thinking it was an npm issue):

```
npm uninstall axios
npm cache clean --force
npm install axios
npm uninstall axios
npm cache clean --force
npm install axios -S
```

in my app.js file I have the following listed as axios states to do with node:

```
const axios = require('axios');
```

I also tried the following:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;  //I figured this would not work because I am not using typescript
var axios = require('axios');
```

When I run my local server in npm I get this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\WebDevelopment\Newsletter-Signup\app.js:4:15)
```

I am running npm v5.0.0 and node v8.0.0
I have checked several stackoverflow pages for the solution but none of them seemed to offer a solution to this issue. Here are the pages I have checked:
[import axios from axios - Parsing error: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707360/import-axios-from-axios-parsing-error-unexpected-token)
[Unable to load Axios in Node even though it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092696/unable-to-load-axios-in-node-even-though-it-is-installed)
[Why do I get an error while trying to install axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66559260/why-do-i-get-an-error-while-trying-to-install-axios)
[Module not found when new dependency is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558502/module-not-found-when-new-dependency-is-installed/55612124#55612124)
[Javascript require method is not finding axios module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66757527/javascript-require-method-is-not-finding-axios-module)

I also looked at the GitHub page and couldn't find a solution:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2082
Here is where I am using axios:

```
function onClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute(secrets.recaptcahUrl, {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
        // Add your logic to submit to your backend server here.
        axios.post(secrets.recaptcahUrl, {
          secret: secrets.recaptchaSecretKey,
          response: token
        })
        // logic to validate response token here
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response); //I wanted to log it first to see what is returned
        })
        .catch(function (error){
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

and

```
app.post(home, (req, res) => {

  // onSubmit(this);
  const user = BuildNameAndEmail(req);
  onclick(res);
// I am doing more stuff but it is unrelated to axios
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Thats a rather old version of node I wonder if it could be related to that? [According to a github comment](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2323) they build for v10 of node and lower version may not work.

Comment: "I am running npm v5.0.0 and node v8.0.0" - but why? They're ancient, even LTS ended years ago.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using this old versions

Comment: You know what, these versions are probably the reason. I need to use the old version to run our microservices at my company -- it's bad I know. I am going to upgrade these to latest stable and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find any official document related to your issue. Found nothing but a GitHub discussion that says:

> We build for the lowest of v10, any lower than that is not guaranteed
> to work.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2323

I guess this is the reason you are having this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your version of node won't work with the latest version of axios. Instead use an older version of the axios library. You can install it like this:

```
npm install --save-exact axios@^0.27.2
```